# Problem when performing an update user mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, prisma

I have a settings page where the user can update their email, first name, and last name. I am wrapping the entire settings  component with a User component which contains all the data props for a user. Data is being pulled in and displayed in the input fields just fine, but I am getting the following error when I submit the data from the settings component:

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: You provided an invalid argument for the where selector on User., Location: , Path: updateUser

Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: You provided an invalid argument for the where selector on User.
```

**schema.graphql**

```
...
# import * from './generated/prisma-client/prisma.graphql'

updateUser(email: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, password: String): User!
...
```

**Mutation.js**

```
async updateUser(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    // First check if there is a user with that email
    const user = await ctx.db.query.user({ where: { email: args.email } });
    if (user) {
      throw new Error(`The email ${args.email} is already being used`);
    }
    const updatedUser = await ctx.db.mutation.updateUser({
      where: { id: args.id },
      data: {
        email: args.email,
        firstName: args.firstName,
        lastName: args.lastName
      }
    });
    return updatedUser;
  }
```

**Frontend Mutation:**

```
const UPDATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation UPDATE_USER_MUTATION(
    $email: String!
    $firstName: String!
    $lastName: String!
  ) {
    updateUser(email: $email, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName) {
      id
      email
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`;
```

If it helps, I can also provide the full Settings.js component. I'm still learning GraphQL/Apollo, so I'm sure I'm making an obvious mistake, but can't find where. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

**EDIT:** Adding the Settings.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";
import { Mutation, Query } from "react-apollo";
import { Button, Flex, Card, Box } from "rebass";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import Link from "./Link";
import Text from "./Text";
import Error from "./ErrorMessage";
import User, { CURRENT_USER_QUERY } from "./User";

const UPDATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation UPDATE_USER_MUTATION(
    $id: ID!
    $email: String
    $firstName: String
    $lastName: String
  ) {
    updateUser(
      id: $id
      email: $email
      firstName: $firstName
      lastName: $lastName
    ) {
      id
      email
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`;

const StyledInput = styled(Box).attrs({
  as: "input",
})`
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 15em;
  border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.greys[1]};
  padding: 0.5em;
`;

const UpdateSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email("Invalid email address")
    .required("You must enter an email address"),
});

const Settings = props => (
  <User>
    {({ data: { currentUser } }) => (
      <Mutation
        mutation={UPDATE_USER_MUTATION}
        refetchQueries={[{ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY }]}

      >
        {(updateUser, { error, loading, called }) => (
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              id: props.userId,
              email: currentUser.email,
              firstName: currentUser.firstName,
              lastName: currentUser.lastName,
            }}
            validationSchema={UpdateSchema}
            onSubmit={values => {
              updateUser({
                variables: {
                  email: values.email,
                  firstName: values.firstName,
                  lastName: values.lastName,
                },
              });
            }}
            render={({
              values,
              errors,
              touched,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit,
            }) => (
              <Flex
                flexDirection={["column"]}
                mb={[2, 0]}
                width={1}
                alignItems="center"
                height={1}
              >
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post">
                  <fieldset disabled={loading} aria-busy={loading}>
                    <Box>
                      <Error error={error} />
                      <Box mb="30px">
                        <label htmlFor="email">
                          <Text my={2}>Email</Text>
                          <StyledInput
                            placeholder="Enter your email address"
                            type="email"
                            name="email"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            value={values.email}
                          />

                          {!error && !loading && called && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="green" pt={1}>
                              Email successfully updated!
                            </Text>
                          )}

                          {touched.email && errors && errors.email && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="red" pt={1}>
                              {errors.email}
                            </Text>
                          )}
                        </label>
                      </Box>

                      <Box mb="30px">
                        <label htmlFor="First Name">
                          <Text my={2}>First Name</Text>
                          <StyledInput
                            placeholder="Please enter your first name"
                            type="text"
                            name="firstName"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            value={values.firstName}
                          />

                          {!error && !loading && called && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="green" pt={1}>
                              First name updated!
                            </Text>
                          )}

                          {touched.firstName && errors && errors.firstName && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="red" pt={1}>
                              {errors.firstName}
                            </Text>
                          )}
                        </label>
                      </Box>

                      <Box mb="30px">
                        <label htmlFor="Last Name">
                          <Text my={2}>Last Name</Text>
                          <StyledInput
                            placeholder="Please enter your last name"
                            type="text"
                            name="lastName"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            value={values.lastName}
                          />

                          {!error && !loading && called && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="green" pt={1}>
                              Last name updated!
                            </Text>
                          )}

                          {touched.lastName && errors && errors.lastName && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="red" pt={1}>
                              {errors.lastName}
                            </Text>
                          )}
                        </label>
                      </Box>
                      <Box>
                        <Button type="submit" width={1} primary>
                          Update
                        </Button>
                      </Box>
                    </Box>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
              </Flex>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </Mutation>
    )}
  </User>
);

export default Settings;
export { UPDATE_USER_MUTATION };
```

Comment: How can updateUser mutation know which user to update? Lets try to pass id

Comment: I added the Settings.js file. So I should add `variables={{ id: props.id }}` to my Mutation so that it gets passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing an id in the frontend mutation so backend is receiving null and throwing this exception.

Please provide it in the frontend mutation.

```js
const UPDATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation UPDATE_USER_MUTATION(
    $id: ID!
    $email: String!
    $firstName: String!
    $lastName: String!
  ) {
    updateUser(id: $id, email: $email, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName) {
      id
      email
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`;
```

**EDIT**: Also update the `schema.graphql` file

```
...
# import * from './generated/prisma-client/prisma.graphql'

updateUser(id: ID!, email: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, password: String): User!
...
```

**EDIT**: Also update the react component like so:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";
import { Mutation, Query } from "react-apollo";
import { Button, Flex, Card, Box } from "rebass";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import Link from "./Link";
import Text from "./Text";
import Error from "./ErrorMessage";
import User, { CURRENT_USER_QUERY } from "./User";

const UPDATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation UPDATE_USER_MUTATION(
    $id: ID!
    $email: String
    $firstName: String
    $lastName: String
  ) {
    updateUser(
      id: $id
      email: $email
      firstName: $firstName
      lastName: $lastName
    ) {
      id
      email
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`;

const StyledInput = styled(Box).attrs({
  as: "input",
})`
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 15em;
  border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.greys[1]};
  padding: 0.5em;
`;

const UpdateSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email("Invalid email address")
    .required("You must enter an email address"),
});

const Settings = props => (
  <User>
    {({ data: { currentUser } }) => (
      <Mutation
        mutation={UPDATE_USER_MUTATION}
        refetchQueries={[{ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY }]}

      >
        {(updateUser, { error, loading, called }) => (
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              id: props.userId,
              email: currentUser.email,
              firstName: currentUser.firstName,
              lastName: currentUser.lastName,
            }}
            validationSchema={UpdateSchema}
            onSubmit={values => {
              updateUser({
                variables: {
                  id: currentUser.id,
                  email: values.email,
                  firstName: values.firstName,
                  lastName: values.lastName,
                },
              });
            }}
            render={({
              values,
              errors,
              touched,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit,
            }) => (
              <Flex
                flexDirection={["column"]}
                mb={[2, 0]}
                width={1}
                alignItems="center"
                height={1}
              >
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post">
                  <fieldset disabled={loading} aria-busy={loading}>
                    <Box>
                      <Error error={error} />
                      <Box mb="30px">
                        <label htmlFor="email">
                          <Text my={2}>Email</Text>
                          <StyledInput
                            placeholder="Enter your email address"
                            type="email"
                            name="email"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            value={values.email}
                          />

                          {!error && !loading && called && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="green" pt={1}>
                              Email successfully updated!
                            </Text>
                          )}

                          {touched.email && errors && errors.email && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="red" pt={1}>
                              {errors.email}
                            </Text>
                          )}
                        </label>
                      </Box>

                      <Box mb="30px">
                        <label htmlFor="First Name">
                          <Text my={2}>First Name</Text>
                          <StyledInput
                            placeholder="Please enter your first name"
                            type="text"
                            name="firstName"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            value={values.firstName}
                          />

                          {!error && !loading && called && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="green" pt={1}>
                              First name updated!
                            </Text>
                          )}

                          {touched.firstName && errors && errors.firstName && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="red" pt={1}>
                              {errors.firstName}
                            </Text>
                          )}
                        </label>
                      </Box>

                      <Box mb="30px">
                        <label htmlFor="Last Name">
                          <Text my={2}>Last Name</Text>
                          <StyledInput
                            placeholder="Please enter your last name"
                            type="text"
                            name="lastName"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            value={values.lastName}
                          />

                          {!error && !loading && called && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="green" pt={1}>
                              Last name updated!
                            </Text>
                          )}

                          {touched.lastName && errors && errors.lastName && (
                            <Text fontSize={1} color="red" pt={1}>
                              {errors.lastName}
                            </Text>
                          )}
                        </label>
                      </Box>
                      <Box>
                        <Button type="submit" width={1} primary>
                          Update
                        </Button>
                      </Box>
                    </Box>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
              </Flex>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </Mutation>
    )}
  </User>
);
```

Comment: I added that and now I am getting this error `Unknown argument "id" on field "updateUser" of type "Mutation".` It seems like 'id' might not be getting passed to the mutation now?

Comment: Just forgot, you will require to add it in schema.graphql file as well. Updating the answer @JonLeopard

Comment: Thanks! So I added that, but I cannot seem to pass the id parameter correctly. I tried adding `variables={{ id: props.id }}` as part of the mutation, but that didn't seem to do the trick either. I'm getting `Variable "$id" of required type "ID!" was not provided.` right now. I added the Settings.js file so you can see how I am writing the component.

Comment: try adding this to onSubmit
` onSubmit={values => {
              updateUser({
                variables: {
                  email: values.email,
                  firstName: values.firstName,
                  lastName: values.lastName,
                  id: currentUser.id
                },
              });`

Just copy paste the component from above.

Comment: That worked! You are a lifesaver, thank you so much!